# django - access variables in template

Tags: django, django-views

I have a database containing books. On mysite.com/books, this database is presented in table form, with the title and the author displayed as columns and books are rows.

When a user clicks on a book title, it leads to a details page: mysite.com/books/slug-of-specific-book. I have managed to get this working fine, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to access the information of the specific book on the details page. Namely, I'm uncertain if I'm configuring my view for this correctly. I'd like to be able to access something like {{ book.name }} in the template page for the details page and have that display at the top, for instance.

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("Details", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

urls.py

```
 url(r'^books/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', inventory.ShowDetails.as_view(), name="Details"),
```

views.py

```
 class ShowDetailedListing(ListView):
     template_name = "detailed_book.html"

     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

Could someone please give me some pointers on how to write this view so that I can access something like {{ book.name }} in "detailed_book.html"? I tried seearching online for this (as it seems really simple), but couldn't quite find anything, probably because I'm not sure how to phrase this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin) might be more appropriate than list view since it seems you want to display information on 1 object

you can set the `context_object_name` to book

Using detail view should automatically map the slug field in your url to the slug on your Book model

```
class BookDetailView(DetailView):
  model = Book
  context_object_name = 'book'
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing DetailView to my attention!